# Existen otras alternativas para medir el tiempo de ejecución en linux que no sea con el comando time?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

saben como podría medir el tiempo de ejecución de un programa en linux Ubuntu sin usar el comando time?

Comment: ¿Qué tal [usando date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52347/500774)?

Answer (score 0):

Además de la respuesta dada por @Jaime en los comentarios (respuesta que me parece la mejor aproximación), se me ocurrió hacer una implementación de *time*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export time=0

show_time() {
    echo "Tiempo transcurrido: $time segundos"
    exit
}

timewatch() {
    trap show_time SIGINT
    local time_interval=1
    while : ; do
        ((time=time+time_interval))
        sleep $time_interval
    done
}

# Implementación de función "time"

my_time() {
    local func_name="$1"
    
    timewatch &
    timewatch_pid=$!
    
    $func_name

    kill -s SIGINT $timewatch_pid
    wait $timewatch_pid
}

# Funciones para probar

random_func3() {
    echo hola
    sleep 3
    echo adios
}

random_func2() {
    echo hola 2
    sleep 2
    echo adios 2
}

my_time "random_func3"
my_time "random_func2"
```

Cuyo resultado me da las imprecisas cifras de:

```
$ ./timing
hola
adios
Tiempo transcurrido: 3 segundos
hola 2
adios 2
Tiempo transcurrido: 2 segundos
```